# Vue component (vue-flatpickr-component) rendering outside <div id="app">

Tags: html, vue.js

I am using the Vue component [vue-flatpickr-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-flatpickr-component). I have noticed that part of the component is being rendered outside of the **div id="app"** tag.

The issue is that I would like to change the CSS that is attached to the class outside of  dynamically (light/dark mode).

My questions:

- Why is part of the component outside of the main div tag?
- How can I get that component into the main div?

Code below:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <flat-pickr v-model="date"></flat-pickr>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import flatPickr from "vue-flatpickr-component";
import "flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    flatPickr,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      date: new Date(),
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

From the Console:

[image: From the Console:]

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed something similar on our project.

Seems like the `static` option from the [flat-pickr documentation](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/) will do the trick here, assuming the styling is setup to override flat-pickr's default.

> Position the calendar inside the wrapper and next to the input
> element. * Attaching the calendar to a specific element makes it
> depend on that element’s position and style. If the calendar is not
> positioned as expected, check the CSS rules of the container.

Set that as a config option where the flat-pickr component is brought in:

`<flat-pickr :config="config" v-model="date"></flat-pickr>`

then define the config option within the data variables like:

```
data: function () {
    return {
      config: {
        static: true,
      },
```